# Grab the new list label

Tags: lists, enumitem

My question is very simple: when I define a new list using `enumitem` how can I get the label that is used? I now that I can do that with `\label` ... `\ref` (as it is in the MWE), but I need a descriptor similar to `\@itemlabel` for the new list, because I want to use it in other command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{lista}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[lista]{label=(\arabic*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{lista}
    \item AAAA
    \item BBBB\label{i:test}
    \item CCCC
\end{lista}

Just a test~\ref{i:test}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define a new `enumerate` based environment, `enumitem` defines as many counters as specified, in your case just one called `listai`. If you define two levels they would be `listai` and `listaii`.

Inside the environment, you have also `\labellistai` that expands to `{(\arabic{listai})}` and can be used with `\edef` (or `\protected@edef` if you use commands unsafe for `\edef` such as `\textbf` in the definition of the label).

Comment: Thanks! `\labellistai` is the command that I was looking for.